Can path-connectedness be defined using connectedness?
Can there be a "useful" and a non-trivial property $P$ for general spaces such that we have "Path-Connectedness $\iff$ Connectedness $\land$ $P$"?
I know "Path-Connectedness $\iff$ Connectedness" holds in locally path-connected spaces, but that is not what I want here. This doesn't answer my question either as it asks for properties $P$ such that we have "$P$ $\implies$ (Path-Connectedness $\iff$ Connectedness)".

If $P = $ "each point has a path connected (clopen) neighborhood", then "Path-Connectedness $\iff$ Connectedness $\land$ $P$".

If the top answer in the link does not answer your question, you should explain what kind of an answer would be satisfactory or at least why you found the other answers to be unsatisfactory.
